# Azure webjob failed

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

i am running my azure webjob on a schedule.
most of the times, it runs successsfully, but sometimes it fails with a exit code exit code -532462766.

```
[10/26/2015 18:00:05 > 8a1006: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[10/26/2015 18:00:05 > 8a1006: SYS INFO] Run script 'Something.WebJob.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[10/26/2015 18:00:05 > 8a1006: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[10/26/2015 18:01:09 > 8a1006: INFO] Starting someIndexLoader...Finished someIndexLoader.
[10/26/2015 18:01:14 > 8a1006: INFO] Starting someotherIndexLoader...Finished someIndexLoader.
[10/26/2015 18:01:18 > 8a1006: ERR ] 
[10/26/2015 18:01:18 > 8a1006: ERR ] Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'myapp.Common.Logger' threw an exception. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry.RemoteDependencyModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry' could not be loaded.
[10/26/2015 18:01:18 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.CreateInstance(Type interfaceType, String typeName)
[10/26/2015 18:01:18 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstance(XElement definition, Type expectedType, Object instance)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstances[T](XElement definition, ICollection`1 instances)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstance(XElement definition, Type expectedType, Object instance)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadProperties(XElement instanceDefinition, Object instance)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadInstance(XElement definition, Type expectedType, Object instance)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.LoadFromXml(TelemetryConfiguration configuration, XDocument xml)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.get_Active()
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient..ctor()
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at myapp.Common.Logger..cctor() in d:\abc\swap\myapp.Common\Logger.cs:line 17
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at CneCrmSearch.Common.Logger.LogException(Exception exception, IDictionary`2 properties)
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at myapp.Common.IndexLoaders.someIndexLoader.LoadIndex(Boolean dropAndCreateIndex) in d:\abc\swap\myapp.Common\IndexLoaders\someIndexLoader.cs:line 241
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: ERR ]    at myapp.WebJob.Program.Main() in d:\abc\swap\myapp.WebJob\Program.cs:line 28
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: INFO] Starting some2IndexLoader...
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[10/26/2015 18:01:19 > 8a1006: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using App Insights to log exceptions inside `LogException`?

Comment: Yes, I am using App insights to log exception